# ms access displays strings with E as exponent

Tags: ms-access, string-formatting

I have a field in MS Access like 
Condition Onset = 2
and diagnosis code as E86
Actual field value is 2E86
Field is "Text" and I want the field to display just as text but Access insists on displaying as 2.00E+8'6

How can I force it to display as entered?

Thanks in advance
Mick

Comment: Are you sure that table data type is Text? Looks like the field data was wrongly imported. What do you see if open table directly?

Comment: Thanks Sergey, but of the >200,000 rows less than 1% contain "E" but only records with "E" cause the fault.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the Format property set to: *Standard*

Change that to: *@*

Comment: Access even applies exponentiation during the conditional clause WHERE ([DIAGNOSIS_CDE_1]<>[Principal diagnosis]);